# Adding functionality to a button in Odoo 11

Tags: button, odoo

i want to make a button which remove the current players in a game.
These are my class in models.py

```
class pista(models.Model):

 _name = 'bowling_module.pista'
 id_pista =  fields.Integer(string="Número pista",  required = True)
 estado = fields.Selection([('0','Desuso'),('1','Jugando'),('2','Mantenimiento')],string = "Estado de la pista")
 descripcion = fields.Text(string = "Notas de la pista")
 jugador = fields.One2many('bowling_module.jugador', 'pista', required = True)
 _sql_constraints = [
     ('PK_NM', 'unique (id_pista)','Ese id ya existe')]


class jugador(models.Model):
_name = 'bowling_module.jugador'
pista = fields.Many2one('bowling_module.pista', 'id_pista', required = True)
nombre = fields.Char(string = "Nombre de cliente", required = True)
pie = fields.Integer(string = "Numero de jugador", required = True)
```

The views.xml

```
  <record model="ir.ui.view" id="bowling_module.pista">
  <field name="name">Listado de pistas</field>
  <field name="model">bowling_module.pista</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree>
      <field name="id_pista"/>
      <field name="estado"/>
      <field name="descripcion"/>
      <field name="jugador"/>
      <button name="Eliminar" string="Eliminar" class="oe_highlight"/>
    </tree>
  </field>
</record>
```

I can add the button and see it. But. How can i add functionality? I want to remove the current players[Removing players](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qzfu.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to create a view in XML like the following:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="bowling_module.pista">
      <field name="name">Listado de pistas</field>
      <field name="model">bowling_module.pista</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <tree>
         <field name="id_pista"/>
         <field name="estado"/>
         <field name="descripcion"/>
         <field name="jugador"/>
        <button name="Eliminate" string="Eliminar" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
     </tree>
 </field>
 </record>
```

Then, create one method in Pista class like the following:

```
    def Eliminate(self):
       for record in self:
           for line in record.jugador:
                line.unlink()
```

When You click on this button at that time this method is executed and unlink your records.

May this Work.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add method for that like this

```
def Eliminate(self):

   for record in self:
       for line in record.jugador:
            line.unlink()
```

Comment: Where? in Pista class?

Comment: Yes in pista class

Comment: That's not enough, because the button is declared as `action` (default type in views). You have to redefine it as `type="object"` to use the method above. And additionally `jugador` is required, change that because it doesn't makes any sense.